How to convert RowBoxes into list of math expressions?
I have following RowBox which represents Step By Step solution of undefined integral
RawBoxes[StyleBox[FormBox[StyleBox[GridBox[((StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Take the integral:', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]],)]],), (RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', RowBox[(RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['cos', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], '+', '1')]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'x')])])],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 2 >>, Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])], Rule[GridBoxSpacings, (Rule['Columns', ((None,),)], Rule['Rows', ((0.5,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Multiply numerator and denominator of ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['1', RowBox[(RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['cos', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], '+', '1')]], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' by ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2060', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], RowBox[(RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], '+', '1')]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'x')])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Prepare to substitute ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['u', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('tan', '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['. Rewrite ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], RowBox[(RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], '+', '1')]], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' using ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[(RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], '+', '1')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2060', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(TagBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], RowBox[('2', '+', RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')])]], HoldForm], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'x')])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['For the integrand ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], RowBox[('2', '+', RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')])]], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[', substitute ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['u', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('tan', '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' and ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('\uf74c', 'u')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['sec', '2'], '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('\uf74c', 'x')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['u', '2'], '+', '2')]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'u')])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Factor ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['2', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' from the denominator:', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', RowBox[('2', ' ', RowBox[('(', RowBox[(FractionBox[SuperscriptBox['u', '2'], '2'], '+', '1')], ')')])]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'u')])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Factor out constants:', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]],)]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', '2'], RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', RowBox[(FractionBox[SuperscriptBox['u', '2'], '2'], '+', '1')]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 'u')])])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['For the integrand ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['1', RowBox[(FractionBox[SuperscriptBox['u', '2'], '2'], '+', '1')]], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[', substitute ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['s', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['u', SqrtBox['2']], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' and ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('\uf74c', 's')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['1', SqrtBox['2']], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('\uf74c', 'u')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', SqrtBox['2']], RowBox[('∫', RowBox[(FractionBox['1', RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['s', '2'], '+', '1')]], RowBox[('\uf74c', 's')])])])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['The integral of ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['1', RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['s', '2'], '+', '1')]], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[' is ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', RowBox[('-', '1')]], '(', 's', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', StyleBox[RowBox[(StyleBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', RowBox[('-', '1')]], '(', 's', ')')], SqrtBox['2']], (GrayLevel[0], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])], '+', StyleBox['"constant"', (Rule[Magnification, Times[0.9, Inherited]], Rule[FontSize, Inherited], Rule[FontFamily, 'Roboto'], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])])], (GrayLevel[0.6], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Substitute back for ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['s', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[FractionBox['u', SqrtBox['2']], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', StyleBox[RowBox[(StyleBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', RowBox[('-', '1')]], '(', FractionBox['u', SqrtBox['2']], ')')], SqrtBox['2']], (GrayLevel[0], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])], '+', StyleBox['"constant"', (Rule[Magnification, Times[0.9, Inherited]], Rule[FontSize, Inherited], Rule[FontFamily, 'Roboto'], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])])], (GrayLevel[0.6], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])]), 'RowDefault'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],), (StyleBox[GridBox[((Cell[TextData[(StyleBox['Substitute back for ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox['u', TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox['\u2009\uf7d9 ', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[('tan', '(', 'x', ')')], TraditionalForm]]], GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], StyleBox[':', GrayLevel[0.3], Rule[StripOnInput, False]])]],), (FrameBox[StyleBox[GridBox[((StyleBox[TemplateBox[('"Answer:"',), 'RowDefault'], Rule[FontFamily, 'Roboto'], Rule[FontSize, 12], Rule[StripOnInput, False]], '\uf3ba'), ('""', TemplateBox[('" "', '"\uf7d9 "', StyleBox[RowBox[(StyleBox[FractionBox[RowBox[(SuperscriptBox['tan', RowBox[('-', '1')]], '(', FractionBox[RowBox[('tan', '(', 'x', ')')], SqrtBox['2']], ')')], SqrtBox['2']], (GrayLevel[0], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])], '+', StyleBox['"constant"', (Rule[Magnification, Times[0.9, Inherited]], Rule[FontSize, Inherited], Rule[FontFamily, 'Roboto'], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])])], (GrayLevel[0.6], Rule[LinebreakAdjustments, (1, 100, 1, 0, 100)], Rule[LineIndent, 0])]), 'RowDefault'])), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Baseline,),)])], << 2 >>, Rule[GridBoxSpacings, (Rule['Columns', (2, 0, 3)], Rule['Rows', (1.5, 1, 2)])], Rule[AllowScriptLevelChange, False]], 'Grid'], Rule[FrameStyle, Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], RGBColor[0.52, 0.76, 0.86]]], << 2 >>, Rule[FrameMargins, 12], Rule[StripOnInput, False]],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 1 >>, Rule[DefaultBaseStyle, 'Column'], Rule[GridBoxItemSize, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((Automatic,),)])]], 'Column'],)), Rule[GridBoxAlignment, (Rule['Columns', ((Left,),)],)], << 4 >>, Rule[GridBoxSpacings, (Rule['Columns', ((Automatic,),)], Rule['Rows', ((3,),)])], Rule[FrameStyle, GrayLevel[0.7]]], 'Column'], TraditionalForm], 'Output', << 9 >>, Rule[ScriptLevel, 0], Rule[Background, None]]]

I want to write function which will extract strings and math expressions from RowBoxes and store in the list similar to this one
{"Take the integral:",Integrate[Times[1, Power[Plus[Power[Cos[Global`x], 2], 1], -1]], Global`x],"Multiply numerator and denominator of ", .....}


